# How do you pick up items discovered by the Dowsing Machine (Dowsing MCHN)?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

My Dowsing Machine discovered a hidden item and I traced it according to its directions. The machine is now showing me a set of cross-hairs. How do I pick it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are standing where you are so the cross-hair appears. Then, move one step towards any direction and turn 180 degrees so you are facing the hidden item. Press A like you normally would to pick it up.